# Window.OnBeforeUnload

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am trying to create a customisation to our existing software, which launches on this event. I need to be able to catch the window.onbeforeunload again once the user has made their choice.

I have tried wrapping the functions but can't seem to be able to overwrite the one which is loaded first. Does anyone have any ideas about how I can approach this, or force the newly assigned function to overwrite the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cancel the unload depending on which button the user presses, and you can not invoke this event manually.  [It's not even a standard event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).  Think of the vulnerabilities that could be used for malicious purposes if the event had the capabilities you want it to have.

This is about all you can do...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  alert("one"); // First time, choose to stay on page
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert("two");  // Second time
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah fair enough. The user can cancel the unload though if they click to stay on the same page. I've had to use 'onunload' instead.

Comment: @DavidYell Yes `unload` does not give a user dialog, and it is a standard event.  Note that it fires every time the page unloads (not just when the user closes the window)

Comment: This doesn't work.. onbeforeunload needs to return a string for there to even be a choice.